# gdb: unknown target exception 0x406d1388

Tags: c++, mingw, gdb

GDB вечно выдаёт ошибку:

```
gdb: unknown target exception 0x406d1388
```

Однако, запуск .exe файла проходит успешно.
Использую minGW для компиляции.
Если нужно обновится, то как это сделать?

Comment: Это не ваш случай? http://stackoverflow.com/q/40923437/276994

Comment: @VladD Отличие лишь в использовании cygwin. Я уже пытался использовать его GDB, но он требует библиотеки cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Это специальное техническое исключение, которое сообщает отладчикам (Delphi студия, визуалка и др.) название потока. В поддерживаемом отладчике потоки получаются проименованы, что помогает понять, что вообще происходит. gdb, видимо, в той версии про этот трюк не в курсе и реагирует. Надо игнорировать это исключение.